# get R console to highlight errors in red

Tags: r, error-handling

A lot of the time I paste code for evaluation into the R console. Sometimes errors occur in the middle of the statements I pasted and I miss them because they blend in with the rest of the stuff on the screen. Is there a way to make them stand out via color coding?

Comment: Pro Tip :-) :  when you've got that much untested code, don't try to run it all at once.  Even better, avoid writing code which spews to the console (aka stdout).  Write all your results to an object or twelve, thus cleaning up the console output.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: could you please elaborate? this sounds like really useful advice!

Comment: Alex - depends a bit on what you're doing.  Basically, instead of executing commands or functions which write their output to the console,  include a line like `return(invisible(list_of_outputs))` and then execute `myfunction(...) ->testout` .  The warning & error msgs will show up on the console, and your data will be in the new variable `testout` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: oh yeh i do that already. it's just things get lost when you are pasting code. thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On linux or mac, you can simply load the **colorout** package and your errors will show up in red.

[image]

Comment: this thing isn't on cran and i'm a bit nervous about installing things that change base R.. anything else that does stuff like this?

Answer (score 3):

from `?base::options` error: either a function or an expression governing the handling of non-catastrophic errors such as those generated by stop as well as by signals and internally detected errors. If the option is a function, a call to that function, with no arguments, is generated as the expression. The default value is NULL: see stop for the behaviour in that case. The functions dump.frames and recover provide alternatives that allow post-mortem debugging. Note that these need to specified as e.g. options(error=utils::recover) in startup files such as ‘.Rprofile’.

So, I guess you could modify your .Rprofile to handle errors differently, if stopping is too much maybe you can surround them with some line-breaks to make them stand out in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

`stop("an error occurred")`

`message("an error occurred")`

`cat("error occurred", file=stderr())`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/).  It has many color options for the console and file text that are really simple to change.

Here's how mine looks. It makes error, warnings, and messages really easy to spot.

[image]

Comment: i am using R remotely via a cluster (even interactively) on linux. my understanding is that RStudio cannot be used for this purpose, correct?

Comment: @Alex, I'm not sure. Sorry. Searching the RStudio link might answer that question.