# Colored output in R console, esp. colored errors

Tags: r, user-interface, error-handling

`colorout` is [no longer on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorout/index.html). As @user2647661 points out below, the package is still being maintained and can be downloaded from the [author's website](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/colorout.html).

My question: Is there another R package that provides similar functionality or at least a quick hack that shows errors in red? (I use R inside a Gnome Terminal on Ubuntu.)

I am aware of [Alex's question about printing errors in red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465962/get-r-console-to-highlight-errors-in-red). @Eric Fail's answer suggests that something like this can be build using error handling functions. However, I am not familiar enough with R to fully understand his suggestion. Has anybody implemented something like this yet?

Comment: Pretty much everyone uses an editor or a GUI that provides syntax-coloring and parentheses matching. You could use an old school approach of "vi" or "emacs" or the newer RStudio approach. Linux users can also use RKward, although I'm uncertain if it plays well with Gnome.  http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I use Sublime Text but I haven't yet found a proper way to integrate it with R (and then get proper highlighting of errors and the like). There is [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), but it has a nasty bug where it stops updating fairly randomly.

Comment: Supposedly there is menu support for selecting R syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 2 : http://tomschenkjr.net/using-sublime-text-2-for-r/

Comment: I think we are now mixing two different issues: Syntax highlighting is for *code*. What I am looking for is a package to colorize *output*. (Apologies for taking 1.5 years to return to this discussion.)

Comment: I tested the compiled-from-source version of colorout on both the Mac GUI where it failed, but we already get output errors in red, and in a Mac Unix console where it was effective in 'red'-ifying _output_ errors. It requires a display that accepts ANSI control characters, so I would expect it to succeed in a NIX environment. So I guess I don't understand the question.

Comment: The question is whether there is another package that does the same thing but is available on CRAN.

Answer (score 2):

The package is no longer on CRAN but it's still being maintained. Please, look at http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/colorout.html

Comment: This is the same as the accepted Answer to the Question that the OP links to.  But, +1 because I like colorout so much.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I edited the question to make it more obvious.